# Update Lead Owner using Flows/ visual Flow

Tags: field-update, flow, record

I created a flow with many choices, one of them is update the Lead Owner,it takes you to a screen where you choose 1 user from a list of users and in the Flow I save the User Id but when I hit Next this happens: "An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information."
I checked and the Owner Id is Null but I'm not sure if I am saving it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post what you are doing in each step that is causing the problem. Basically you should have the picklist choices that have values of the user ids, save the choice to a variable, and then update that variable into your lead object.

Comment: In addition, you should receive an email with more detailed information on the issue. Looking at your debug log is also a good way to go.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out using this video: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2XbYeeFb8
I did exactly the same thing using my variables and it worked. Thanks for replying to my question though!
- First saving the Id that I needed into a Variable, then creating a Fast Lookup to save a Sobject Variable with the Id of the record I want to update.
- Then create an assignment window that Saves the NewOwnerId into the Record Id using {!varLeadToUpdate.OwnerId} and last..
-Use "Fast Update" to update the record.
If anyone has a question in regards of this answer please add a comment and I would be happy to help you with it.

Comment: I hope the answer looks better now, it basically explains the same thing the video shows.